# Ninject binding setup

Tags: parallel-processing, ninject-2, ninject.web.mvc

I have a weird case where I'm using NInject and I'm not sure how to proceed.  Our repositories in this instance are custom-written sql generators, and not using linq to sql; nHibernate, etc.

In order to utilize code within the system, we're, within the implementation of the repositories, injecting the required repositories to build child objects (e.g., an "order" object needs to get its "orderdetails" objects and assign it to the order before returning it to the calling area in the system, so in our OrderRepository, we have an [Inject]IOrderDetailRepository OrderDetailRepo { get; set; }).

What the hangup comes in is up until this point, we've been able to keep everything configured InRequestScope().  Now we are using a Parallel ForEach loop and after an iteration completes, we're firing an event over to a singleton scoped event handler to update the database.  We'd do the update within the loop, but have been trying to avoid tying the loop with a particular area in the system, since there could be many areas that could use this loop.

So, we need to figure out when we call into this singleton scoped event handler, how to have ninject configured that all IRepositories (IOrderRepository and IOrderDetailRepository) used within that singleton event handler die off and init immediately when they are used.

Any Hints?

---

So, I have "A" resolution, but I'm not happy with the resolution for this... what I did was to build-up a ChildKernel and then set the bindings the way that I wanted to have them.  Although this works as expected, it feels like some serious "code smell".  Would love to see a better way of handling this scenario, if one would exist.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I don't get what you are trying to do.